# SQL Server 2019 Express for Linux on Ubuntu 20.04 - Bug - CU 13 - c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION when specifying @wkt in Table-valued function

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu, spatial, crash

Pretty sure I've found a bug in SQL Server 2019 (Express) for Linux (CU 13, version 15.0.4178.1 running on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS).  After the following table-valued function dbo.bTest is created:

```
use devdb
go

drop function if exists dbo.bTest;
go

create function dbo.bTest ( @p_geom geometry )
Returns @geometries TABLE
(
  id integer,
  geom geometry
)
as
begin
  Declare
    @v_g geometry;
  set @v_g = @p_geom.STBuffer(0.1);
  insert into @geometries values ( 1, @v_g);
return;
end;
go
```

And the following query is executed the first time, I get no error:

```
select * from dbo.bTest(geometry::Point(0,0,0));
go --the first time this runs, it behaves as expected
```

But execute the same query a second time and SQL Server 2019 for Linux (CU 13) crashes with a c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION:

```
select * from dbo.bTest(geometry::Point(0,0,0));
go --the second time this is run, c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION on Linux
```

Again, the following runs fine the first time through:

```
select * from dbo.bTest(geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(0 0)',0));
go --the first time this is run, it behaves as expected
```

But execute it again and:

```
select * from dbo.bTest(geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(0 0)',0));
go --the second time this is run, kaplow, c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION on Linux
```

It only does this on the Linux version of SQL Server (Express) 2019.  Not getting any error using Windows versions of SQL Server.

BTW, if the query is re-written like so:

```
declare @g geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(0 0)',0);
select * from dbo.bTest(@g);
GO --this is a work-around, no error when executed once

declare @g geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(0 0)',0);
select * from dbo.bTest(@g);
GO --or twice, works as expected, no error
```

Then it runs fine, no error no matter how many times it is executed.

Anyone else experiencing this under SQL Server for Linux?

Comment: You can check it on Centos too. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=22622ab2755952d75f9c4955516df284

Comment: Excellent, thanks @McNets, wasn't aware there was a dbfiddle for this.